# how to make slicing with dimension time,lat,long netcdf using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in Python.  I am getting an error on the following python code. How to make a slicing time using three-dimension which is time, lat and long in NETCDF format using python. The dimension is time, lat and long which the shape is (288,361,720)

```
 from netCDF4 import Dataset
 import NumPy as np
 import xarray as xr
 nc = Dataset ('path.nc')
 print (nc)




for i in nc.variables:
     print (i, nc.variables[i].units,nc.variables[i].shape)

     lat = nc.variables['latitude']
     long = nc.variables['longitude']
     time = nc.variables['time']
     shww = nc.variables['shw']

for d in nc.dimensions.items():
    print (d)
    nc = nc.variables[0,:,:]
    print(nc)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\ProcessTry\file.py", line 37, in 
        nc = nc.variables [0,:,:]
     TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: checkout the type of `nc.variables`.also why, there is a space after nc.variables (line 37)?

Comment: still the same error ...

Comment: You should specify the variable you want to slice, i.e. line 37 should be nc = nc.variables['shw'][0,:,:] if you want to slice 'shw'.

Comment: I have specified the variable that I want to slice. It seems  get error too..